# Destructor call line

Tags: c++, gcc

I would like to find a file and a line(gcc `__FILE__`, `__LINE__` defines) of place where destructor is called. I managed to handle this in case of constructor with parameters passed to the wrapper class.

As destructor can't take any parameter, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Looks like [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. You might want to tell us what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @MatthewRock I'm trying to track shared pointer usage on per address basis.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`backtrace()` and `backtrace_symbols()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html) on linux but C++ provides no standard feature for walking the stack.

If you're just trying to understand execution in order to debug, you should attach with a debugger and set a breakpoint at the destructor.

---

If you have shared pointers and you care about who actually cleans up afterwards, then you likely don't want to be using shared pointers.  Change your design to use non-owning references (`std::weak_ptr`) everywhere other than the true owner of the memory.

Comment: It's embedded project, not based on linux . I don't have access to debugger.

Comment: The problem I have is temporary. Std::weak_ptr won't do, I needed just to find where in code is created additional shared_pointer so, the object it points to is not deleted.

Comment: It sounds remarkably like `weak_ptr` is the way to go.  Why won't it work?